# C++ Operator Overload for Functions

Tags: c++, function, lambda, operator-overloading

I'm writing a program in which I want to be able to ultimately perform some standard operations (such as a +, -, *) on `double`-`double` functions (by `double`-`double` functions I mean things that take one value of type `double` and spit out something else of type `double`, whether these be hard-coded or lambdas). So I'd like the following examples to be possible:

```c++
#include <functional>

double f(double x)
{
    return x + 5;
}

double g(double x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<double(double)> h   = f + g;
    std::function<double(double)> h_  = (f - g) * 5;
    std::function<double(double)> h__ = f * g;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried something like the following form, but it the compiler still doesn't seem to like me adding two things of type `double(double)` together.

```c++
std::function<double(double)> operator+(std::function<double(double)> &f, std::function<double(double)> &g)
{
    return [=](double x)->double{ return f(x) + g(x); };
}
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing that could help this to work? As a current workaround I'm calling a function of form and calling it with the correct arguments, but I can't get it to work naturally with operators.

```c++
std::function<double(double)> add_two_functions(std::function<double(double)> &f, std::function<double(double)> &g)
{
    return [=](double x)->double{ return f(x) + g(x); };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that `f` and `g` are function pointers and, therefore, `operator+` cannot be applied to them. You need to cast those function pointers to `std::function<double(double)>` objects.

Something like the following would work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

double f(double x) {
    return x + 5;
}

double g(double x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

std::function<double(double)> operator+(std::function<double(double)> const& f,
                                        std::function<double(double)> const& g) {
    return [=](double x) -> double {
        return f(x) + g(x);
    };
}

int main() {
    using FuncType = double(double);
    std::function<FuncType> a{ reinterpret_cast<FuncType*>(f) };
    std::function<FuncType> b{ reinterpret_cast<FuncType*>(g) };

    auto h = a + b;

    std::cout << h(2.0) << std::endl; // 11
    return 0;
}
```

Check [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTMAOUgAdUCwuto9QxNBHz81Ohs7RyMXN05FZUxVAIYCZmICIONTcyUVCNo0jIIoh2dXD0V0zOyQhIUa0tty2MrOAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZltkQywAanFhnXVG4kxmIxnscQAGAEERsYnMadmqA1oUujZVje2t9B6ndkmqCBuDO/2ADw7pgHZZLcn/yaLAi9WiTN7TGSTACsM1%2B2y%2BABFLpdnq9JsAnrd7h9vnCAYDMMDiKDJJMAFRg2HIxHIraNdAgEBHE6FGY6VHsTEvdgdVaTVBeVzMIjEOQQemM5mnWhsjmYLmvXnDbCTNC0RpSABsD1Il3x%2BoNhqNxsmEqZx2lsqx8rlSpVao1km1wE%2B4h%2BeoBQJB0yhsmGSKhCIV2M%2BAFo%2BXLcR6DV7iQ8IDi5OiE0q8QC3UjhnCM7TNrYCJMjMxbBBXe6/gCDH5RJMAGIWgAqAE9BQcEZM5cHMKno6aCAzzSyAmz6ydm4K%2Bcw3dICfnXF4gQB9Fga2aj5DjzBk1bUMuZtP/M1S1lrxstzB8pzT2f0edLlcEEdnwXb5XQPdUra95gGIiTBBtpMzAQjOV5Zrm%2BJmmgv4HDobL/hAkgAHTrK6szwWalisJ%2Bmz4rGoLrDhGYDF0rAgAMUIDKQpgDOsVGoORcEyEmCg9H0%2BwjJwVEEORdEdF0ADWIBQshkhfJwULcOs3CagAnLJXzDO47hQkI5HcFRNF0aQDEDFRCggOspA8bRJGkHAsAwIgKCoEYXh4OwZAUBAaB2Q5lTALJ5hUA5BCuAZEBOLxVFOLYGRNuRXGkK5RhaAQADytCsBFpmkFgRaiOwwVpXgiwpAAbpgBmpZgbzJL%2BgzaXOZGpaweBOMQ4V6FgkXccQeBGK1XQ0PQTBsBwPD8IIwiiCgchyEI9UGZAXQCoUxWhvSMwIhIzEyJIzD6Uk0qaNodSmAklhlDEcShL4/h0PtZ3hAEx0VPEiQFKkTRXQ022FMUmR3W0D2NCUr3VCU32nZ03S9P0XCkeRlHUdlulvO4mqhpq3DosgyCTLJSGkhAuCECQELDAkkx6G5jmE50JPjTI3HBfxpBCcM6xIe43BfF8kjDF80mI5qUKampAwaaQnVQkZWn0eR%2BmGcZdPmVZEBID0BBeL%2B5CUK59mOYImD4CKgg9YwLBZYNADujVeF1gswxLOnkZxkym4QAEI0jKNoxjWOSLTpn0wgSxYG4paC8Lovi3DUuKDLJl8YJIBs0hHOs1CslQkz6xOpwEmC8MmkR3psu%2B1DAze7DqW6T7sekIVxB%2BBo3BAA%3D%3D)

Answer (score 0):

In `f + g`, `f` and `g` decay to function pointers. A function pointer is not valid to use in addition, and you cannot overload operators for function pointers.

That said, you really don't need to.  You can just use a lambda like

```
int main()
{
    auto h   = [](auto var){ return f(var) + g(var); };
    auto h_  = [](auto var){ return (f(var) - g(var)) * 5; };
    auto h__ = [](auto var){ return f(var) * g(var); };

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, its more verbose, but its clear what you want to have happen.